# Отображение полученных снимков экрана

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

Здравствуйте. Помогите мне, пожалуйста, решить проблему.
Написал программу, которая делает снимки чужого экрана (сервер + клиент).
Вот результирующая функция (которая находиться в приложении "сервер") получения изображения:

```
 public Bitmap getScreen()
        {
                int cursorX = 0;
                int cursorY = 0;
                bmpCursor = CaptureCursor(ref cursorX, ref cursorY);
                r = new Rectangle(cursorX, cursorY, bmpCursor.Width, bmpCursor.Height);
                bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, <br>Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
                gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);
gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, <br>CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
                gfxScreenshot.DrawImage(bmpCursor, r);
                gfxScreenshot.Flush();
                return bmpScreenshot;
        }
```

Получает она изображение всего монитора + мышки.

В приложении клиент я в `pictureBox.Image` присваиваю мою функцию, так как она возвращает `Bitmap`, вешаю всё это на таймер, делаю `pictureBox1.Invalidate()` (перерисовываю). Но полученные изображения всё равно накладываются каскадом друг на друга. В чём проблема, не пойму.

Comment: попробуйте ``pictureBox.Refresh();``

Comment: пробовал , не помогло

Comment: ``pictureBox.Image = null;//new Bitmap(pictureBox.Width, pictureBox.Hight)
pictureBox.Refresh();``

только возможно будут проблемы с NullReferenceException

Comment: это очевидно , тоже пробовал

Comment: если в ``pictureBox.Image`` ничего или путой рисунок, почему ``pictureBox.Refresh()`` отрисовывает старый рисунок О__о

Comment: так а я и не говорил что проблема в pictureBox...., скорей всего проблема с Graphics (у меня переменная класса Graphics - gfxScreenshot)

Comment: Что значит каскадом? Друг на друга со смещением по X и Y?

Answer (score 2):

Я, конечно, не силен в шарпе (C#), но из опыта работы с графикой при рисовании обычно надо выполнить нечто типа `canvas->clear();`  т.е. очистить/залить прошлые зарисовки.

Comment: делаю pictureBox1.Invalidate() - перерисовываю

Answer (score 1):

Используй [Graphics.Clear](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.graphics.clear(v=vs.110).aspx) для очистки перед рисованием.

И вообще, ты бы мог просто bitmap присваивать в `Image`.